# NSTableView Selection Slowness

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4

I am using `NSTableView` for my mac os x(desktop application).  I am working in Mac os 10.6(snow leopard). My problem is when I select all the rows in the `NSTableView`, using a select all button, the rows that are currently visible for the table, gets selected.  When I scroll down and see for the remaining rows, they are not get selected. Can anyone find a solution for this problem?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you any code to share with us? You haven't provided nearly enough information to help you.

Comment: What do you mean "select all button"? Are you using the Edit > Select All menu item, aka Command-A ?

Comment: the table contains a list of files. In the code, the sent action for the select all button contains only this code [my_table selectAll:nil]; select all is the name that i gave to the check box button @trudyscousin